# How to make HTML5 fullscreen mode in firefox like chrome?

Tags: html, css, fullscreen

On [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode) site you can read: "[...] if you're trying to emulate WebKit's behavior on Gecko, you need to place the element you want to present inside another element, which you'll make fullscreen instead, and use CSS rules to adjust the inner element to match the appearance you want."

Is there another solution to emulate Webkit´s behaviour?

Comment: `DUPLICATE QUESTION` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16408780/how-to-make-firefox-fullscreen-mode-like-chome-i-e-not-streching-content

Comment: @Fags that does not have an upvoted or accepted answer.